# How to clean up or format a disk after shred command is executed

Tags: cleanup

I have a system with a mounted drive, we have ran the shred command and now the disk is showing as 100% used.
How do I clean up or format the disk now? So that it can be reused.

Comment: Please tell us the exact command you used to shred. Did you shred the whole drive or just a partition? Was any partition mounted while shredding?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you shredded the partition like this:

```
shred -vfz -n 5 /dev/sdX
```

Then you can go into GParted, remove the partition(s), then create new. Format the new partition, and you’ll be golden.

Comment: There are no partitions left if you shred the whole drive like `dev/sdx`, it will really shred the whole drive, including partition table.